# How does sorting(Order by) be implemented in Hive?

Tags: sorting, hadoop, sql-order-by, mapreduce, hive

We know that hive doesn't do sampling before a sorting job start.It just leverage the sorting  machenism of MapReduce and perform merge-sort in reduce side and only one reduce is used.Since reduce collects all data output by mapper in this scenario,say a machine running reduce has ony 100GB disk, what if the data is too big to fit in the disk?

Answer (score 0):

The parallel sorting mechanism of Hive is still under development, see [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1402).

A well designed data warehouse or database application will avoid such global sorting. If needed, try using [Pig](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#ORDER) or Terasort(http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/examples/terasort/package-summary.html)